# For a couple of weeks, results seem to appear twice?

Tags: support, search

1, I go to stackoverflow, 2, I type in to search say "unity3d", 3, I click "newest".

Traditionally, I'd just see all the (most recent) Unity3D questions.

But now it seems to show both questions and any answers to the same question, in the list.  So, I see two (or more) entries for every relevant item.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a setting?  Is this a change? Is it a bug?

Cheers

Comment: It always worked like this, as far as I know. Use `is:q` to search questions and `is:a` to search answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting different results - one for the question, one for the answer (see the Q and A near each one?), which is how things have always worked.

You can constrain the results to either questions (using `is:q`) or answers (using `is:a`) if you wish.

Comment: Thanks @Oded:  (1) is there some setting I can apply so that it will always default to is:q ?  (2) man, I'm pretty certain that for me, for many years, it worked in the "only q" paradigm.  at a certain point (about two weeks ago - it took me until now to ask here) it started working (for me) as it now does ... does that seems possible to you?

Comment: Again, mostly, is there some setting I can apply so that it will always default to is:q ?  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeBlow - no, no such setting, AFAIK. I've seen questions/answers returned for years now, is it possibly you just started noticing two weeks ago? ;)

Comment: Say, I'll tell you something else that may be of interest: presently, I search "unity3D".  At first you get the default "Relevance", right?  Nobody wants to look at "Relevance", you just click to "Newest".  I do all this zillions of times a day for years.  Check this out: on the "relevance" list at the moment.  the top item is a silly question ("Sitelock .unity3d").  Let me explain: for some reason that particularly bad question ("Sitelock .unity3d") is "stuck" as the top Relevance question.  **Indeed**: that problem started for me, about two weeks ago, at the same time as the "is:q" issue...

Comment: In short, the "Relevance" list has been stuck for me for about two weeks (I notice that lame question "Sitelock .unity3d" at the top every single time, before I click through to "Newest".)

Comment: "is it possibly you just started noticing"  :)  of course that's possible, heh.  I'll leave it to you thanks for the input.

Comment: Summary: (1) something is screwed / stuck with the Relevance list as I see it.  (2) For God's sake, change the default to is:q  (3) for God's sake make the default "Newest", not "Relevance" !  Cheers

Comment: Have you checked out the "new nav" at all? Near the bottom of [your preferences page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/294884), you can opt into that - see if the new navigation works for you better.

Comment: Thanks for that info, if I get time (pretty unlikely) I'll check it out. Cheers

Comment: hi @oded if you see this: not a big deal, but as I mention above the "Relevance" tab is definitely stuck for me.  The same lame question  ("Sitelock .unity3d") has been the one and only top item under "Relevance", for me, for 6? weeks now.  Just letting you know. Cheers